# How to split data into 3 parts, one of which wont be used?

Tags: scikit-learn

I've got a csv that I want to split 80% into training, 10% into dev-test and 10% into test set. The dev-test wont be used further.

I've got it set up like:

```
import sklearn
import csv
with open('Letter.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   annotated_data = [r for r in reader]
```

and for splitting:

```
import random  
random.seed(1234)  
random.shuffle(annotated_data)
```

But all the splitting I've seen only slips into 2 sets, and I can't see where to specify how much partition to split it with, eg I want 80% training. Maybe I'm blind, but can anyone help me? I don't know how to use pandas.

Also once I split it, how do I access the sets separately? For eg I can read each record as a whole and count the amount of entries, but once I split it I want to count how many records are in each set. Sorry if this deserves its own post, but I don't want to spam.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's possible in scikit-learn to split into three sets directly.
The typical approach is two split twice.in 80/20 and then split the 20 percent 50/50. You want to check the [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)-function.

Essentially, the code with data `X` and `y` could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(100).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)

X_train, X_tmp, y_train, y_tmp = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_dev, X_test, y_dev, y_test = train_test_split(X_tmp, y_tmp, test_size=0.5)
```

Now you would want to work with `(X_train, y_train)`, `(X_dev, y_dev)` and `(X_test, y_test)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) twice:

1. Split the data into a ratio 0.8 : 0.2
2. Split the smaller set into a ratio 0.5 : 0.5